# How I can derive the Neuman boundary condition of this system of hyperbolic equations in 1D?

Tags: pde, matlab, finite-difference

I would like to research the Neuman boundary that can verify the following problem

$\begin{aligned}
&\text { (} P \text { )}\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}(x, t)+A \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}(x, t)=0, \quad x \in[a, b], t>0 \\
U(x, 0)=U_{0}(x), \\
\frac{\partial U}{\partial \eta}=?
\end{array}\right.\\
&U(u, t)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
u(x, t) \\
v(x, t)
\end{array}\right), \quad U_{0}(x)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
cos(x) \\
sin(x)
\end{array}\right)\\
&\text { and }\\
&A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)
\end{aligned}$

I've already find the exact solution using the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of $A$:

$U=\left(\begin{array}{l}
cos(x-t)+sin(x-t)-sin(x+t)\\
   \qquad sin(x+t)
\end{array}\right)\\\\$

However, I straggle in calculating $\frac{\partial U}{\partial \eta}$

First of all, I know that $\frac{\partial U}{\partial \eta}=\nabla U.\eta \quad$   but the operator $\nabla$ is define on the space of function $f: \mathbf{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}, \text { so that } \nabla f: \mathbf{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{n}$, so I conclude that the notation of $\frac{\partial U}{\partial \eta}$ is incorrect. For this reason, I presume that I have to research for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta}$ separately, the problem that I still face is that I'm not sure if $\eta$ it is $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ ? to me $\eta$ is the normal derivative it need to be normal on the abscise axe, so it should be $(0,1)$ but I'm not sure of that.
I don't know where I have a problem because I need to approach the exact solution whith the finite difference method using Matlab , but none of the case works for me, so I need to be sure that the error doesn't come from my calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial \eta}$$ means usually $$\eta \cdot \nabla U$$. This is correct even if the domain is the interval $[a,b]$. The normal vector on the interval $[a,b]$ @a is $\eta=-1$ and @b $\eta= 1$ both pointing outwards of the domain. Hence in 1D $\frac{\partial U}{\partial \eta}$ means $$\eta\cdot\nabla U=\eta \frac{dU}{dx}$$.